# document.onkeypress in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a web page which listens for any keypresses and sends a POST request to a server to obtain some data. Using the data returned back, I wanted to render that onto the webpage.

Originally, to get keypresses, I had an HTML file and in the header, I had a script tag which looked something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
        var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        console.log(charStr);

        var params = {
          key: charStr
        };

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        console.log(form);
        form.method = "post";
        form.action = "http://localhost:8888/";

        for (var key in params) {
          if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.type = "hidden";
            hiddenField.name = key;
            hiddenField.value = params[key];
            console.log(hiddenField);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
          }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
      };
    </script>
```

Now I'm using React as I want to listen for any keypresses and render the returned data onto the webpage without having to refresh. I have a component which looks something like this

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      x: null,
      y: null,
      z: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/some-endpoint")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        returnData => this.setState(returnData),
        () => console.log("State has been set to the return data")
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.x}</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.y}</h2>
        <h2>{this.state.z}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want to do is basically have that script that I was running in the HTML snippet above running somewhere in this component, but I'm unable to simply copy paste it into a script tag in my div and return it along with the HTML as I get errors saying stuff like "')' expected" and I'm really not sure what they mean in this context.
I feel like I may be approaching this the wrong way, but basically, I want to be able to add that functionality into my web page with React. I think it would have to be in the same component as `myComponent` to tell this component to update its state, but I could be wrong about that. If anyone can point me along the right path or give me some guidelines, that would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have not built your code, but that then is definitely super wrong. This part is fine: `returnData => this.setState(returnData)`. I'm not sure what you want to do with the other function, but your syntax is busted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you'll want to add your event listener inside `componentDidMount` and destroy the listener inside `componentWillUnmount`.

You'll also want to move your handler into a seperate function within the class to reference when you're destorying the listener.

It should look something like this:

```js
class myComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress.bind(this))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress)
  }

  handleKeyPress() {
    fetch('/some-endpoint', { method: 'POST' })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(respJson => this.setState(respJson))
  }
}
```

One thing to note, is that in your code snippet, the syntax for handling the response of the fetch is invalid.

---

A helpful resource is this documentation page on the React website:

https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

Comment: Implemented this solution. The other solution was similar as well and was helpful too but this is the one I went with as it was neat. Thank you! The link was handy as well

Comment: I'm happy to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to add the `script` tags to render, you can just add the code inside the `script` tags to `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.onkeypress = evt => {
    ...
  };

  fetch("/some-endpoint")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      returnData => this.setState(returnData,
      () => console.log("State has been set to the return data")
    ));
}
```

Also, I notice that your parentheses are in the wrong place, which could be the reason for the error you're seeing. See the second `.then` above, you should move the right paren from `returnData` to after the `setState` callback.